# I am not able to add facebook login in my website .. it redirects and again shows LOGIN button ,,

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

```
<?php 
session_start();


require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('abc','xyz');

$required_scope     = 'public_profile, email';

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://www.example.com/' );

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}



if ($session){ //if we have the FB session
    $up = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

    echo $up->getId();
    echo $up->getName();
    echo $up->getFirstName();
    echo $up->getMiddleName();
    echo $up->getLastName();
    echo $up->getLink();
    echo $up->getBirthday();
    echo $up->getLocation();
}
else
{
   echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => $required_scope )) . '">Login to FB</a>';
}
?>
```

when i click on login button it redirects to fb login page , now after giving email_id and paasword it prompts for allowing access for pernmissions which the example.com wants ,, after allowing it redirects to redirect url but it is not showing any user info.. it shows login button again... It seems like it returns session false

Comment: i am in big trouble... can`t solve this .. please help in this..

Comment: well, no help needed.. solved it myself.